# Visual Studio Error : Unrecognized Guid format

Tags: c#, visual-studio, solution

I have a solution containing CSharp projects and Python projects in a specific folder.

I just added a **Directory.Build.targets** into the root of the folder as following:

```
<Project>
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Shared.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
    <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
        ... commands
    </Target>
</Project>
```

After that, when I'm running the VisualStudio again in the output I have some errors because of Python projects:

> ..[path][projectName].pyproj : error  : Unrecognized Guid format.

Any idea how can I exclude the python projects from the **Directory.Build.targets**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Add a condition, such as

```
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(MSBuildProjectExtension)' == '.csproj'">
        <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Shared.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

This will include this group (in this case with a reference) only if the current project is a C# project.

Comment: I tried this one but the issue is still there! When I'm loading the python projects it says "Unrecognized Guid format."

Comment: It seems the issue is because of <Project> tag not the ItemGroup!

Comment: And you're sure it's because of this reference? Can you post the exact error message you get? Because this doesn't have much to do with Guids.

Comment: The issue is exactly because of this file but it was just gone when I remove this file. Not even with comments the contents.

Comment: Thanks, It has been solved!
I just added the condition but didn't work! then I closed the VS and open it again worked!